# Is this a PHP bug on date?

Tags: php

Doing this on PHP 5.6.14:

```
$a = strtotime('2016-10-01');
$b = $a+29*24*3600;
$c = $a+30*24*3600;
die(date("d/m/Y",$b).' - '.date("d/m/Y",$c));
```

will return `30/10/2016 - 30/10/2016`

How strange since I expect `$c` to be `31/10/2016` instead of `30/10/2016`. Is it a PHP bug?

Notes: I know there are several ways to do date operations, but I'm asking specifically on this. If I change the `$a` month to other numbers than 10 (e.g. 8,9,11,12) it gave me expected results.

Comment: Always check your assumptions `var_dump($a, $b, $c)`. You assume b and c have certain values, but you assume wrong.

Comment: This is also why `DateTime` is a superior way to add dates in PHP

Comment: I'm thinking this has to do with daylight savings time - as if you also output with the hour as well, you'd get `30/10/2016 00:00 - 30/10/2016 23:00`, and we subtract one hour (because of DST) October 30th (in at least my country).

Comment: Thanks guys! Noted Qirel. I haven't thought about it coz I live in a country without it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fix this issue is by adding midday like so:

```
$a = strtotime('2016-10-01 12:00');
$b = $a+29*24*3600;
$c = $a+30*24*3600;
die(date("d/m/Y",$b).' - '.date("d/m/Y",$c));
```

The reason why is because you did not include a time so PHP assumed "now" for the time part of `strtotime`. You then have day light savings in October in your country (well, the country of the server) and this pulled back the closing time value of `$c`.

Adding midday (12:00) gives you a buffer. It does not need to be 12:00 as 1:00 would have worked as well but personally I like to work with 12:00.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't thought about it coz I live in a country without it :)

Comment: Just checked the php.ini setting and yes it's "Europe/Berlin". Changing it to "Asia/Jakarta" solved it.

Comment: Happy to have helped.